# Maximum Likelihood Estimation given Uncertain Data

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

during my lecture in uncertainty quantification i came across a problem where one has $2$ machines, that usually have a probability of producing a faulty part of $p1 = 10^{-4}$. Now we know for certain that Machine $1$ works properly, thus has this probability $p1$ of producing a faulty part. Machine $2$ on the other hand is expected to be damaged and has a possibility $p2$ of producing a faulty part. Each of the machines produce $50\%$ of the factories output. One is supposed to find the Maximum Likelihood Estimate for $p2$ given that $1000$ parts are examined, without knowing from which machine they came, and one faulty part is found.
I dont know how to handle the uncertainty in the data? What is the Likelihood function, given that I dont know wheter the faulty part is from machine $1$ or $2$?

Comment: If you knew $p_1$ and $p_2$, what would be the probability of $1$ faulty part out of a sample of $1000$ as a function of $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: Ahh I think i got it know, the probability of a part beeing faulty is $P(F) = P(F|M_1)*P(M_1) + P(F|M_2)*P(M_2) = \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}$ and from there I have a bernoulli distribution for every part  and with a dataset of $1000$ parts i can get the MLE $P(F)_{MLE} = \frac{1}{1000}$ and thus $p_2 = 1.9*10^{-3}$